# wordpress get second featured image in slider thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working on a wordpress theme and i want to get the slider thumbnail from second featured image and for that purpose i used a "multiple featured image" plugin but i am unable to get it. infact want to get that second featured image only not the first one. i used it on page not on post.

here is the code for plugin registration

```
if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {

    $args = array(
            'id' => 'featured-image-2',
            'post_type' => 'page',      // Set this to post or page
            'labels' => array(
                'name'      => 'Featured image 2',
                'set'       => 'Set featured image 2',
                'remove'    => 'Remove featured image 2',
                'use'       => 'Use as featured image 2',
            )
    );

    new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args );
}
```

this is the code where it shows default thumbnail and i want to replace it with my 2nd featured image.

```
<ul>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $featured_num; $i++) { ?>
        <li> <a href="#"<?php if ( $i == 0 ) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
                    <?php print_thumbnail( array(
                            'thumbnail'     => $arr[$i]["thumbnail"]["thumb"],
                            'use_timthumb'  => $arr[$i]["thumbnail"]["use_timthumb"],
                            'alttext'       => $arr[$i]["titletext"],
                            'width'         => (int) $small_width,
                            'height'        => (int) $small_height,
                            'et_post_id'    => $arr[$i]['post_id'],
                            'title'         => $titletext,  
                    ) ); 

                    ?>
                    <span class="overlay"></span>
                </a>

        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

and here is the code that i want to work for me but dont know where i amdoing wrong.

```
<?php
            if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'page' );
                } ?>
```

i tried my best to explain my problem so if you guys need extra info that i missed then let me know.

Comment: "new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args );" wouldnt be something like "obj =  new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args );"

Comment: is there any one who could help me why its viewed only 6 times in 13 minutes

Comment: no this is not the issue and i also tried it but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
    $image_id = kd_mfi_get_featured_image_id( 'featured-image-2', 'page' );
    kd_mfi_the_featured_image( $image_id, 'page' );
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for reply back but unfortunatiely its not working

Comment: @kwk.stack is your WP_DEBUG option set to true? if not please turn it on, thanks

Comment: No it was false but its true now what to do next as no effect on issue

Comment: @kwk.stack ok, do you see any warning or notice during page view?

Comment: on deactivate and then activate i got this message Notice: Undefined property: kdMultipleFeaturedImages::$args in C:\ after set debug to true

Comment: this is the line number 69 where it refere for the issue  $this->nonce        = 'mfi-'.$this->args['id'].$this->args['post_type'];

Comment: this is the message on page view Notice: Undefined property: kdMultipleFeaturedImages::$args in C:\

Comment: but i remove that notice message by replace line 69 with this $this->nonce = 'mfi-'.$this->id.$this->post_type; so no more notices but issue still exists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36319/discussion-between-kwk-stack-and-iemanuele)